# Relationship between groups and permutations

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

What is the relationship between groups and permutations? The way I understand it, a permutation is a set of numbers that you can do things with. A group is a set of elements equipped with an operation. So how do they relate?

What operation would a permutation have on it? Do the group axioms apply to permutations?

Comment: There are "permutation groups", however a permutation is defined as a bijective function from a finite set to itself.  "*A permutation is a set of numbers that you can do things with*" is almost completely wrong.  What you may be thinking of is $S_n$, the group of permutations on the set $\{0,1,2,\dots,n-1\}$ with group operation being function composition.

Comment: you might want to read about the [Symmetric Groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_group)

Comment: and this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%27s_theorem

Comment: Actually, in the old days of algebra, what they mean by a group was a set of permutations, and if you look to the **cayley's theorem**, you can see that, up to isomorphism, every group is actually a group of permutations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A permutation isn't so much a set of numbers you can do things with, as a thing you can do with an ordered set of numbers. In particular, a permutation is a function that rearranges numbers (or other objects). Permutations are the elements in a permutation group, and the operation on the group is composition of those functions. The group axioms apply to sets of permutations with the operation of composition.

That's how permutations give rise to groups. The interesting fact going the other way (Cayley's Theorem) is that every group is isomorphic to a group of permutations. Thus, you can study groups by studying groups of permutations.

Comment: Every finite group is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_n$ for some n.

Comment: I find it very interesting that you mention "ordered set of numbers" in your definition of permutations; can you please talk about that a little? All the definitions I've seen say that a permutation is a bijection from a set to itself; but that really doesn't seem to capture the idea of a permutation. For example, the permutation "swap the first two objects", when applied to the ordered set [1, 2, 3] makes perfect sense, and I think that's how permutations should work. On the other hand, if I say "perform the permutation $(12)$ on the unordered set $\{1, 2, 3\}$ then nothing happens, since

Comment: there is no order in a set. So please, if you could clear up this long-standing confusion for me, why doesn't the traditional definition of a permutation involve ordered sets in any way?

Comment: Hi, thanks for asking! You're right, of course, that the formal definition of a permutation doesn't involve an "ordered set". A bijection from a set to itself is a more general idea, and we can apply it in contexts where we wouldn't consider thinking of an order on our sets. (Consider a permutation on the complex numbers...) On the other hand, thinking of a permutation as a rearrangement of a list is pretty useful for engaging common intuitions - we've all rearranged objects that are ordered, such as books on a shelf, without ever thinking of a bijective mapping from the books to themselves.

Comment: Sets themselves are not endowed with order; however, an ordered set is a perfectly well-defined object. We just have a set, together with a linear ordering on the set. As soon as a set is linearly ordered, any permutation on that set induces a re-ordering. The definition in terms of bijections is preferred, in many contexts, because it requires less structure to talk about.

Comment: @Ovi here's another way: Sets per se don't have an order, but their elements are distinct. In order to list them out you need to, well, *list* them, which imposes an order that isn't part of the set. The bijection definition of permutations says that, whatever order you impose on a set, the permutation puts *this* element in place of *that* element, *that* element in place of *some other* element, and so on through the set

Answer (score 1):

G Tony Jacobs' answer is spot on! Every group is isomorphic to a group of permutations. The proof of Cayley's theorem actually constructs a permutation from each group element, which is elegant and informative.

From a combinatorial perspective, groups were made to act on objects. In particular, every group action has a permutation representation. That is, a group action on an object $X$ can be viewed as a homomorphism from the group into $\text{Sym}(X)$. From a more practical perspective, group actions are used to study automorphisms (or symmetries) of objects. That is, the group action should respect the relation(s) of a given object. If a group $G$ is acting on another group $H$, we respect $H$'s operation. If a group is acting on a graph, we want it to respect the adjacency relation. By respecting the underlying relations, group actions become a powerful tool to leverage the symmetry of an object. One example is the study of vertex-transitive graphs. A graph $X$ is vertex transitive if $\text{Aut}(X)$ acts transitively on $V(X)$. The theory of vertex transitive graphs is well-understood. Godsil and Royle's text on Algebraic Graph Theory is a good reference for this.